# how to include library MPICH2 in MinGW

Tags: mingw, mpi, mpich

i keep getting error :

```
 fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
```

how do i include `mpi.h` as a default library?
i believe i'd already put `c:\MPICH2\bin` on system variable>path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can't find the header file.  The system PATH variable is not related to this.

In order to run the compiler it needs to be on the system PATH (this is where the OS looks up "gcc" when you type it on the command line).  Once GCC is running, it needs to know where header files can be found.  You can add an include path with the `-I` flag:

```
gcc -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/MPICH2/include" -c -o main.o main.c
```

Once that's done, and everything is compiled, the next step is to link the program.  You will need to specify a path to the library with the `-L` flag:

```
gcc -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/MPICH2/lib" -o main.exe main.o -lmpi
```

Normally this is handled by the `mpicc` script so you don't have to worry about this.  The `mpicc` that ships with the pre-built Windows MPICH2 won't work with MinGW out of the box though (I think).

Comment: thanks i've done it with this code
g++ -I"c:\MPICH2\include" testmpi.c -o testmpi.exe -L"c:\MPICH2\include" -lmpi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10. Adding this line in .zshrc (or .bashrc if you use bash shell)

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/openmpi/include
```

did the trick for me